# Power BI Measures with Conditional Filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have what I believe is a simple problem in Power BI, but I'm having trouble solving it.

I have a model with three tables, tbCalendar, tbFiles and tbCategory.

Both the tbCalendar and tbCategory tables have a relationship with tbFiles. tbCalendar's relationship with tbFiles is a many-to-many relationship in a column they both have called "Date" and between tbCategory and tbFiles is a one-to-many relationship made through a column called "Category".

I want to create a measure that makes a distinct count of a column called "KeyCod" of tbFiles where some values are repeated. But I want this measure to ignore all the filters I created except one, the "Date" column filter of tbCategory table to reuse this result in other solutions in my model.

So far I've tried in a few ways, but I haven't gotten the result I need. Could someone help me with this please?

My current measure is:

```
CountKeyCodRows = 
VAR TotalRows = DISTINCTCOUNT(tbFiles[KeyCod])
RETURN CALCULATE(TotalRows,ALLSELECTED(tbCalendar))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace ALLSELECTED with ALLEXCEPT

```
CountKeyCodRows = 
VAR TotalRows = DISTINCTCOUNT(tbFiles[KeyCod])
RETURN CALCULATE(TotalRows,ALLEXCEPT(tbCalendar))
```